# Writing a query that shows the orders and includes a ranking column based on certain specifications

Tags: sql-server

I need help on writing a query that shows the orders and includes a ranking column based on this:
- TotalMoney less than 100 = "LOW" 
- TotalMoney between 100 and 1000 = "MIDDLE" 
- TotalMoney higher than 1001 AND Order was placed after Mar.22, 2005 = "HIGH" - All others "NOTHING" 
- Sort results showing first LOW, then MIDDLE , then HIGH

Comment: Learn how to ask question!!  Where's your attempt???  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be looking at [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) statements within T-SQL to get what you want out of this. 
Example below;

```
SELECT *, Ranking =
    CASE 
    WHEN TotalMoney < 100 THEN 'LOW'
    WHEN TotalMoney BETWEEN 100 AND 1000 THEN 'MIDDLE'
    WHEN TotalMoney > 1001 AND OrderDate > '20050322' THEN 'HIGH'
    ELSE 'NOTHING'
    END
FROM Table
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN TotalMoney < 100 Then 1
    WHEN TotalMoney BETWEEN 100 AND 1000 Then 2
    WHEN TotalMoney > 1001 AND OrderDate > '20050322' Then 3
    ELSE 4
    END
```

Edited, as I was previously unaware that you cannot use aliased column names within an `ORDER BY CASE` statement.

Comment: Thanks but I am not not getting the LOW  to show first in the result.

Comment: @wisdom114 Is the ordering reversed by chance? If so, swap around the numbering in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: I've tried that but the order does not change. Any ideas why?

Comment: @wisdom114 I have just edited my answer. After testing a few things, it appears that the aliased name can't be used in the `ORDER BY CASE` statement. It should now work with the above code.